# Why do HTML table elements have tabs and newlines is this only for readability

Tags: html, parsing, nokogiri, html-table

I am trying to read/parse a web page.  Some of the table elements seem of have many tabs and newlines.

Curious why a few words are preceded by tab/newline.

Answer (score 2):

It's for readability and maintainability. It helps to identify block level and container elements and to ensure that opening tags have closing tags. Basically it is to make the developer's life easier as the browsers do not care about indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely seeing markup like:

```html
<table id="stuff">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Hello World!
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```ruby
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(some_string)
p doc.at('#stuff td').text
#=> "\n\t\t\t\tHello World!\n\t\t\t"
```

As you can see, that really is the text content of that cell.

Comment: Thanks for the great response.  Visually I see multiple lines.  I think they are separated by <br>.  Something like this: apples<br>oranges<br>pine<br> all within a single <td>.  I also see \n and \t.  I think I need to use the <br> as a separator and ignore the \n and \t.  I will get back after I check a few more things.